Interpreting MPT branch node values
Consider a branch node for an MPT.
Suppose the 17’th item in the branch node list is supposed to be NULL, because the branch node is not a “terminator” node. Ethereum documentation says NULL is encoded as the empty string.
Suppose the 17’th item in the list is supposed to be a value because the branch node is a terminator node. Suppose this value happens to be the empty string.
In both cases the 17'th item seems to be the empty string.
How to distinguish these two cases?
Note this question should be independent of RLP encoding, which only concerns how we encode the list. I’m asking what’s in the list itself, before considering how the list is subsequently encoded.

You should replace the incorrect value ("sup") with an empty string ("") in the 17th position of the branch node list.

I don't understand. Not sure what incorrect value you're referring to. What goes in the 17'th position if the branch node has no value? the empty string? What goes in the 17'th position if the branch node has value "" (the empty string)? also the empty string?
